# What are the parameters of addTouchEventListener

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I created class for uiButton creation, there is three function as following;
I created button class there is 3 function in class as following;

```
void MyButtonClass::Create(const std::string &buttonImage, cocos2d::Layer *layer)
{
    myButton = ui::Button::create(buttonImage, buttonImage);
    layer->addChild(myButton, 100);
}

void MyButtonClass::SetPosition(float xPosition, float yPosition)
{
    myButton->cocos2d::Node::setPosition(xPosition, yPosition);
}

 void MyButtonClass::SetTouchListener(Ref *sender, SEL_TouchEvent *selector)//There is problem
{
    myButton->addTouchEventListener(sender, selector);
}
```

How can I set TouchListener? I looked parameters from library but it is not working.

for example create button from my gamescene;

```
button.Create("Play.png", this);
button.SetPosition(100, 200);
button.SetTouchListener(CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::Play, this));//Exception: No viable conversion from '__bind<void (GameScene::*)(cocos2d::Ref *), GameScene *, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>' to 'cocos2d::Ref *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the wrong overload for your situation. You'll want to use the `void addTouchEventListener (const ccWidgetTouchCallback &callback)` overload.
The reason this doesn't work is because no callback is bound to `myButton`. You need to bind a custom callback:

Assuming your button class inherits from a `::cocos2d::ui::Button` or `::cocos2d::ui::Widget`, you need to assign a callback with 
the [Widget::addTouchEventListener()](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.6/d8/d62/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_widget.html#afb1cee076c2cb7c96a8769a68c5a7d90) method.

```
myButton->addTouchEventListener(this, toucheventselector(MyButtonClass::touchEvent));
```

The callback `MyButtonClass::touchEvent` will be invoked when a touchevent for the button is received.

For example:

```
void MyButtonClass::SetTouchListener(Ref *sender, SEL_TouchEvent *selector)//There is problem
{
    myButton->addTouchEventListener([](Ref*, Widget::TouchEventType){
        // Simple callback for touch
        int n = 0;
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

The alternative is to use the methods in `myButton` by setting one or more of the following:

```
onTouchBegan (Touch *touch, Event *unusedEvent)
onTouchMoved (Touch *touch, Event *unusedEvent)
onTouchEnded (Touch *touch, Event *unusedEvent)
onTouchCancelled (Touch *touch, Event *unusedEvent)
```

Check out the codos2d-x doc for the [ui::Button class](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.6/d2/db1/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_button.html#adf271b1be4c753b7f9ddf23e8f67c530)
There is also an example of `onTouchBegan` and `onTouchEnded` [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/EventDispatcher_Mechanism#Create-a-single-touch-event-listener-and-write-the-callback-code).
Instead of `listener1` in this example, you can use `myButton`.

Comment: So how can I use `ccWidgetTouchCallback` parameter in my function. My class is not inherits from `::cocos2d::ui::Button` or `::cocos2d::ui::Widget`.

Comment: You call `addTouchEventListener` on your `myButton` object. You're merely using the incorrect overload of `addTouchEventListener` in `myButton`. The callback can be bound to anything, including a method in your own class.

Comment: I know this already, How can I set event from other class? my uiButton is private in myButtonClass. My SetTouchListener method is public, I want to set custom callback to this method.

Comment: Please see the edit I made. By setting a callback for one or more of them, you can use the existing logic in the cocos2d Button class.

Comment: What is `button` and  `AddTouchEvent` now? Can you post the signature? The error indicated you are trying to pass a function as a parameter that only takes a `cocos2d::Ref*`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84442/discussion-between-valar-morghulis-and-namezero).